# How do I use an arbitrary external program as a filter in a perl program?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I would like to use the current C version of Fletcher Penny's Multi-markdown as a filter in Template Toolkit.  It's not clear to me how to set this up.

At present I'm not calling TT as a module, but simply writing templates that are called with tpage and ttree.

Answer (score 4):

Template-Toolkit filters are actually quite easy to write.

Module:

```
package Template::Plugin::Filter::MultiMarkdown;

use strict;
use warnings;

our @ISA = 'Template::Plugin::Filter';

sub init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->install_filter('markdown');
    return $self;
}

sub filter {
    my ($self, $text) = @_;
    ... Code that transforms $text and returns the transformed text ...
}

1;
```

Usage:

```
[% USE Filter.MultiMarkdown %]

[% FILTER markdown %]...[% END %]
  -or-
[% ... | markdown %]
```

Comment: Text::Multimarkdown is what I'm using now.  Alas, it is modelled on an early version of Fletcher's program and does not produce compliant code, surrounding lots of things with extra paragraph tags.   I will edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: The answer is still the same.

Comment: I'm on a dying phone right now so I only had a quick look, but I think it's probably best if you revert your change to this old question and ask a new one.

Comment: @PerlDuck -- you are correct.  I have deleted that comment and will take ikegami's advice.